# ActiveMQ LeaseDatabaseLocker warning for lease duration

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a slightly strange warning from ActiveMQ 5.9.0 with JDBC Oracle backed persistence...

```
WARN  [org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.LeaseDatabaseLocker] LockableService 
    keep alive period: 2000, which renews the lease, is less than 
    lockAcquireSleepInterval: 1000, the lease duration. 
    These values will allow the lease to expire.
```

My question is why is LockableService reporting that 2000 < 1000? I think it should say "LockableService keep alive period: 2000, which renews the lease, is **greater** than lockAcquireSleepInterval: 1000, the lease duration. These values will allow the lease to expire.". What do you think, maybe I'm reading this wrong...

I do see a problem with my current settings (I have a Master and Slave, I shutdown the Master and the Slave takes over, but I startup the Master again and it doesn't become a Slave)... So I obviously need to tweak my settings, here is the current relevant configuration...

```
<bean id="jdbcPersistenceAdapter" class="org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter">
    <property name="brokerName" value="messageCentreBroker" />
    <property name="createTablesOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="activeMqDataSource" />
    <property name="lockKeepAlivePeriod" value="2000" />
    <property name="locker" ref="leaseDatabaseLocker" />
</bean>
<bean id="leaseDatabaseLocker" class="org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.LeaseDatabaseLocker">
    <property name="lockAcquireSleepInterval" value="1000" />
</bean>
```

So I guess my lockAcquireSleepInterval should be greater than 2000? I'll try this, but interested to hear thoughts on the WARN message too, it seems wrong?

Comment: yep just a typo no doubt, I changed my settings to have a lockKeepAlivePeriod of 7000 and lockAcquireSleepInterval of 14000 actually which worked fine for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a typo. Nothing more.